# REST Service Type if no Data Flow is Involved?

Tags: rest, post, get, patch, put

If I have to consume a service that does not involve data flow between me and the application, what is the most appropriate call type to use? (GET vs POST vs PATCH vs PUT) for the service I am trying to invoke?

The backend however will do couple of modifications to the backend data in datastore and inturn POST it to another backend. However this in not the level of abstraction I look at when I invoke my service. I just want the "process" to be done and how the backend service does it is not material.

In this context how do I denote the "service" I am trying to consume.
Is it a "GET" service as I am getting a service done? This is all very confusing as these verbs are all data-centric and not process-centric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your server does some manipulation in data on the backend, I think you should use `PATCH` and the service should return with code `204 No Content`.

It's pretty much clear, that you need to use either `PUT` or `PATCH`. But what's the difference?

The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in the way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource identified by the Request-URI. In a PUT request, the enclosed entity is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be replaced.

With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the origin server should be modified to produce a new version. The PATCH method affects the resource identified by the Request-URI, and it also MAY have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a PATCH.

So that's why I think `PATCH` will be more suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Ranjan. This is insync with our understanding. I accept your answer.

Comment: Thankyou @GoldenSugar :)

Answer (score 0):

The REST- Methods are very clear in there meaning, not depending on where you send it and whats happening there.

Get is getting something - to ask for some data.
POST is for creating data, PUT is for manipulating existing data.

If you really dont know what is involved at the backend i would prefer PUT since this for me sounds most abstract.

See the definition here:

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: PUT is also for creating data. POST should typically only be used if you are creating a new resource BUT you don't want to allow the client to determine the new URI. If you _can_ use PUT for creation, it is better because it's idempotent.  That website is awful.

Comment: Hey Henning. I hope you don't think I was trying to be mean. I use the downvote button for ansers I feel are incorrect. It's bad advice, so that's why I downvoted. I hope you understand I do appreciate the effort you made answering the question and doing some research.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are invoking a process and not really transfering the state of the resource in any way, I think you are simply not dealing with a REST service.

Given that that's the case, I think the most appropriate HTTP method is simply `POST`. `PATCH` is wrong because with `PATCH` you are supposed to send a message that is intended to manipulate the resource that lives on the target URI. As you said, you are really dealing with a process here which means that:

1. The URI really is not all that meaningful.
2. You're not manipulating resources.
3. You can't guarantee idempotence.

Here are some snippets from the HTTP specification that relate to this:

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the
>      representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's
>      own specific semantics.  For example, POST is used for the following
>      functions (among others):
>
> o  Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
>         form, to a data-handling process;